# How to create, manage, associate a session in REST Jersey Web Application

Tags: java, html, rest, session, web-applications

A HTML5 UI is connected to the backend (REST Jersey to business logic to Hibernate and DB).
I need to create and maintain a session for each user login until the user logs out.

Can you please guide me on what technologies/ APIs can be used.
Does something need to be handled at the REST Client end also..

Answer (score 25):

Using JAX-RS for RESTful web services is fairly straightforward. Here are the basics. You usually define one or more service classes/interfaces that define your REST operations via [JAX-RS annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html), like this one:

```
@Path("/user")
public class UserService {
    // ...
}
```

You can have your objects automagically injected in your methods via these annotations:

```
// Note: you could even inject this as a method parameter
@Context private HttpServletRequest request;

@POST
@Path("/authenticate")
public String authenticate(@FormParam("username") String username, 
        @FormParam("password") String password) {

    // Implementation of your authentication logic
    if (authenticate(username, password)) {
        request.getSession(true);
        // Set the session attributes as you wish
    }
}
```

[HTTP Sessions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) are accessible from the [HTTP Request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) object via `getSession()` and `getSession(boolean)` as usual. Other useful annotations are `@RequestParam`, `@CookieParam` or even `@MatrixParam` among many others.

For further info you may want to read the [RESTEasy User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html) or the [Jersey User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html) since both are excellent resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Suppose I have an user object mapping multiple modules. How do I bind the session to the User object.

Comment: Can you explain how do you mean binding the session to an User object? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I mean to say that, I login from the HTML5 Web UI. Then I want to associate (bind) this User object to the session. This User object bound to the Session is to be used internally everywhere. 

That is to say, whenever I use an Uder object, the respective session id should be always tagged to it.

Comment: is there any demo or tutorial for this? it would be more helpful if there is any tutorials