# How to create a session linked an user on login till logout/ timeout to a web application

Tags: java, hibernate, session, web-applications, jersey

I have a web application with HTML5 UI and connected to the backend by REST(Jersey).

On login to the application, I need to create a session and link it to the current user and un-link it on logout and the same session should be associated with the user for all the other requests/ responses after login.

This should also allow multiple sessions for the same user.

Can you please give me some guidelines/ ideas to understand this better and as to how I can handle this from the backend.

Comment: Are you talking about hibernate session? or the http session?

Comment: If you're talking about an HTTP session you can check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/922058/1154145

Comment: Why do you create duplicates of your own questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377903/how-to-create-manage-associate-a-session-in-rest-jersey-web-application