# Manage entities/user data in Rest Jax-RS Web Service without persisting them to database

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am new to writing JavaEE REST Jax rs web service and I am seeking for a solution to hold/manage all data passed between users/pages and my rest web service without storing them immediately to database?

I am transporting entities/dtos in JSON and only when user clicks on save button in the page, the data shall be stored in the database on application server. What options do I have here? Any ideas? Design pattern or so?

I read the REST services shall be stateless, so what's best practice on this?

Comment: While REST WS are normally stateless, you can still access a HttpSession if you absolutely must. More information can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377903/how-to-create-manage-associate-a-session-in-rest-jersey-web-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use java cache systems like JCS or google guava

[Java cache system](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/)

[Google guava](https://github.com/google/guava)

or if you are using client/server model DB you can use in memory database like SqLite for cache

[Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/)